# How can I display the value stored in my Session Variable in my code behind, in HTML?

Tags: c#, html, json

What I am trying to achieve is to get my session variable called `Session["name"]` in my code behind file and display it on the browser using HTML.

What I had tried initially was to place the session between <%%> tags but that did not work.

This is a line of code from my code behind file:

`string.Format("Welcome, {0}", Session["name"].ToString().Split(' ')[0]);`

What is the best way for me to simply display my welcome message using C# and HTML? I saw stuff about JSON but I really don't understand it nor where to start if that is the route id need to take. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are already creating a session to store name :

```
//Create
Session["name"] = value;
```

Now to show it on the front end or html page you can use label and set text value of that label to the session value as string

```
//Set session text to label
Label1.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
```

Hope this helps